# Getting a Parsing error to a babel plugin

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, eslint, package.json

The error:

> Parsing error: cannot find module babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

> Make sure that all the Babel plugins and presets you are using
> are defined as dependencies or devDependencies in your package.json
> file. It's possible that the missing plugin is loaded by a preset
> you are using that forgot to add the plugin to its dependencies: you
> can workaround this problem by explicitly adding the missing package
> to your top-level package.json.

My eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    browser: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ]
};
```

My .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-exp"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-react-jsx",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"]
      }],
      ["import-rename", {"^(.*)\\.jsx$": "$1"}]
    ]
  }
```

My package.jon:

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-react",
  "version": "1.10.0",
  "description": "Material Dashboard React. Coded by Creative Tim",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.22.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.6",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/dayjs": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/luxon": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "history": "5.0.0",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-chartist": "0.14.4",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.9",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.12",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.9",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "build-package-css": "cp src/assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css dist/material-dashboard-react.css",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Creative Tim <hello@creative-tim.com> (https://www.creative-tim.com/)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://creativetimofficial.github.io/material-dashboard-react/#/dashboard",
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.6",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.9",
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all",
    "last 2 versions"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Comment below if you need any further information. Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Use `import` instead of `require()`.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly

Comment: @Lightning McQueen Still getting the error

Comment: Please add the code of UserProfile.js file.

Comment: Well it mentions this file though in the node-modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-form-eslint:
const resolve = require("resolve");
const eslintBase = require.resolve("eslint");

module.exports = function requireFromESLint(id) {
  const path = resolve.sync(id, { basedir: eslintBase });
  return require(path);
};

Comment: The Error is complaining specifically about UserProfile.js. Could you copy/paste the imports/requires section of this file into a \`\`\` code block \`\`\`, please?

Comment: That issue has been resolved by changing my .eslintrc  to this parser: "@babel/eslint-parser", but now I'm getting a new error of Couldn't resolve babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx. lemme share my updated eslintrc and babelrc